# Electric field $E$ due to a dipole moment

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dipole, dipole-moment

Why is the formula of $$E = kp/z^3~ ?$$ 
Why is it $z^3$ ?
I want a physics answer not math please.

Comment: What makes you think there's always an answer with no math in physics? -1.

Comment: You maybe got me wrong, its not that I don't want math. I know how we got this formula but I wanted a "word" explanation for it. This is what my teacher want to here.

Comment: ... in which case you should edit your question to clarify exactly what you mean. If you want someone to explain a formula with 'no math please', that's got an inherent contradiction built in. Similarly with the secondary questions you've phrased in the comments - you should edit them into the question post itself as comments are liable to be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

A dipole may be represented by a pair of nearby charges of the opposite sign (but the same absolute values), $+Q$ and $-Q$ at a distance $\vec r$ from each other.

At the distance $R$ from the dipole (and I will only consider the case when we measure the field on the axis that includes the dipole itself), one adds $E$ going like $+1/R^2$ from $+Q$, and $-1/(R+r)^2$ from $-Q$, where $r\ll R$. But in this limit (we must know that the electric field from charges goes like $1/R^2$, from the Coulomb's law),
$$ \frac{1}{R^2} - \frac{1}{(R+r)^2} = \frac{ (R+r)^2 - R^2 }{ R^2 (R+r)^2 }=\dots $$
and we expand (without mathematics, use physical platinum models of rectangles to perform the multiplication)
$$ \dots = \frac{R^2+2Rr+r^2-R^2}{R^2(R+r)^2}\sim \frac{2Rr}{R^4} = \frac{2r}{R^3}$$
For $r\ll R$, I could approximate the denominator and neglect $r^2$ relatively to the larger $2rR$ in the numerator. In the result, $2r/R^3$, the factor of $r$ combines with the (universally omitted) factor of $Q$ to give us the dipole $p$, because $p=Qr$, so we get $kp/R^3$. $k=1/(4\pi\epsilon_0)$ in the SI units is the universal coefficient one always inserts to the formula for the electric field from charges, and you used $z$ instead of $R$ (I should have used $z$ as well because I studied the electric field on the $z$ axis only, anyway).

I did these weird expansions to avoid the method of the "derivative" (calculus) but I can't avoid mathematics *entirely*. After all, the very question contains things like $1/R^3$, so it is clearly impossible to address the question without using mathematical symbols of the same kind or their basic meaning or properties.

The operation with the fraction was included to replace what normal adult physicists would do by the derivative of $1/R^2$. If even the fractions are too advanced mathematical one, one could translate the operations with the fractions into plain English and discuss the various powers of $R$, why only integral powers appear, and why all of them cancel and the first surviving term goes like $1/R^3$. But any way to prove these things without the mathematical expressions is just a waste of time. Mathematics is very effective and even if some satisfactory "verbal" proof exists, it is trivially included in the mathematical calculation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but I meant that if we consider a disk and along distance of its center we get coulombs law after math calculations, why not the same  here in the dipole as z goes much bigger than r?

Comment: Disk? The original question surely didn't include the word "disk", did it? A dipole is normally modeled as an infinitely small object. For a large disk comparable to $z$, the formula isn't true, anyway. If the disk - or any shape - is much smaller than $z$, one may use my calculation, anyway. Any electric dipole may be represented by a combination of positive and negative charges arbitrarily accurately. Add them point by point. Each of them will have the field going like $1/z^3$, so the sum will have the same property.

Comment: I know but my teacher asked that why don't we get coulombs law in a dipole like we get in a point far of a disk, i hope i can find a satisfying answer.

Comment: The potential of a charge distribution is $$\varphi= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{K_0}{r}+ \frac{K_1}{r^2}+ \frac{K_2}{r^3}+ \cdots\right]$$ If $K_0\ne 0$ which means there is a net charge, then at large distance the first term would dominate and hence you would get _Coulombic_ field; but if $K_0= 0\,,$ then the second term which is the _dipole_ term will dominate.

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Answer (score 0):

E=k*p/z^3. This is because usually, the Electric field is calculated at a point whose distance from the midpoint of the dipole(z) is very large as compared to distance between the two opposite charges(say a). That is z>>a. Thus, the original value of dipole at a point on the equatorial line=kp/(z^2+a^2)^3/2. as z^2+a^2=z^2.(z>>a). Thus, E=kp/z^3.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but I meant that if we consider a disk and along distance of its center we get coulombs law after math calculations, why not the same here in the dipole as z goes much bigger than r?